# How do I d3.select() on ngFor-inserted <circle>'s?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to `d3.select()` some `ngFor`-inserted circles in order to add a click-event on them. But I somehow can't manage to select them for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to use different selectors such as only `"circle"`, `"circle.connection-point"` and `"circle.connection-point.ng-star-inserted"`

```html
<svg:g [draggable]="temp" [(templateinstance)]="templateinstance">
  <svg #temp class="connection">
    <circle
      *ngFor="let connectionPoints of templateinstance.template.connectionPoints"
      [attr.cx]="connectionPoints[0] + templateinstance.posX"
      [attr.cy]="connectionPoints[1] + templateinstance.posY"
      class="connection-point"
      r="10"
    ></circle>
  </svg>
</svg:g>
```

```
testAddLines(containerElement, elementRef, templateinstance: TemplateInstance) {
    console.log('testAddLines initiated');

    var xy0,
      connectionPath,
      connectionInProgress = false,
      line = d3
        .line()
        .curve(d3.curveStepAfter)
        .x(function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return d[1];
        });

    d3.select(containerElement)
      .selectAll('circle.connection-point')
      .on('click', function() {
        console.log('circle.connection-point');
        connectionInProgress = true;
        xy0 = [
          templateinstance.template.connectionPoints[0][0] + templateinstance.posX,
          templateinstance.template.connectionPoints[0][1] + templateinstance.posY
        ];
        connectionPath = d3
          .select(containerElement)
          .select('path.connection-line')
          .attr('d', line([xy0, xy0]));

        d3.select('svg.canvas').on('mousemove', function() {
          if (connectionInProgress) {
            let mousePos = [d3.event.offsetX, d3.event.offsetY];
            let tempLine = line([xy0, mousePos]);
            connectionPath.attr('d', tempLine);
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

I want to trigger the mouseclick (and following `console.log`) when clicking on circle with class `'circle.connection-point.ng-star-inserted'`.

Comment: What's inside containerElement?

Comment: Additionally, `.select('circle.connection-point.ng-star-inserted')` will select only the first circle, which in turn adds the click listener to only that particular element. You might want to use `.selectAll('circle.connection-point')` instead. The context of your question does also suggest that you may have used the wrong tag [tag:angularjs] which refers to AngularJS a.k.a. Angular 1. AFAIK, `.ng-star-inserted` was introduced with version 5 or later. If you are indeed using Angular you should retag to [tag:angular] to get more specific by people following that tag.

Comment: @AvcS it's the container <g> sent to the function, which works selecting by itself and is used in other functions

@altocumulus I've now changed to selectAll() with no difference. Using just select() did for the record not even select / add the click listener to the first one. Thanks for helping me change to the correct Angular-tag, should be right now.

This is how the code, without success, is looking now:
```javascript
    d3.select(containerElement)
      .selectAll('circle.connection-point')
      .on('click', function() {
        console.log('circle.connection-point');
```